# Deploying Pentaho in Websphere

Tags: db2, websphere, pentaho

I am trying to deploy Pentaho in Websphere. The database I am using is DB2. I get the following error. What can I do to resolve this? Please help

```
[EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener] EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.ERROR_0007_SQLERROR
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: An unexpected token "FROM" was found following "RUNSCRIPT ".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.57.82
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:676)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:60)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:127)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.c(km.java:2506)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.d(km.java:2483)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.b(km.java:1903)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.h(db.java:220)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.b(db.java:46)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.b(t.java:38)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.g(sb.java:114)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.db(km.java:1898)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.a(km.java:2899)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.c(km.java:672)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.executeUpdate(km.java:656)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.pmiExecuteUpdate(WSJdbcStatement.java:1804)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcStatement.java:1135)
        at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.verifyQuartzIsConfigured(EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.java:159)
        at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.startup(EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.java:100)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:364)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.access$000(PentahoSystem.java:58)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:301)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:298)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:340)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:298)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:269)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:182)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1686)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:995)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
    [10/2/14 12:37:55:994 IST] 00000054 SystemOut     O 12:37:55,994 ERROR [Logger] Error: Pentaho
    [10/2/14 12:37:55:996 IST] 00000054 SystemOut     O 12:37:55,994 ERROR [Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener
    org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:306)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:269)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:182)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1686)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:995)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
    Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:372)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.access$000(PentahoSystem.java:58)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:301)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:298)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:340)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:298)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:365)
        ... 33 more
    [10/2/14 12:37:55:997 IST] 00000054 SystemOut     O 12:37:55,997 ERROR [Logger] Error end:
    [10/2/14 12:37:55:998 IST] 00000054 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module null has been bound to default_host[*:9081,*:80,*:9444,*:5063,*:5062,*:443].
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the statement issued by `org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.verifyQuartzIsConfigured()`

Comment: @mustaccio Is this because of missing jar files?

Comment: No, it looks like something is wrong syntactically with the SQL statement you're trying to run at the error point.

Comment: @bhamby These are inbuilt queries inside Pentaho. When I try to start Pentaho, this is the error I get.